# Unstaged Changes in the Atom Editor do not refresh, the editor cannot detect changes

Tags: atom-editor

until yesterday night I could freely use the atom editor to edit my website but today morning there is a strange problem. When I save a file, the change is not visible in the unstaged changes tab so I can upload it....it only gets visible when I close the editor and re open it..

I did not change anything in the git folder etc.

Any insights?

I searched in the web and I did not find anything...I rebooted my pc and nothing happened.

Comment: I have the same issue and am wondering if this has anything to do with atoms sunsetting...

Comment: As nobody answered this question so far, if you haven't already found out, you can actualize the view by executing the fetch in atom.